# Delphi XE2 Indy IRC

Tags: delphi

Indy version: 10.5.8.0
Sometimes program cant disconnect, there is a socket error (i guess there was a problem with server or internet connection) after that is not possible to connect again, app needs to be rebooted. Thanks for help.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    IdIRC1.Connect;
    if IdIRC1.Connected then
      IdIRC1.Join('#' + Edit3.Text);
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdIRC1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdIRC1.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyUTF8Encoding;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdIRC1.Disconnect();
end;
```

Comment: What is the actual error, on which line? 10.5.8 is old, the latest version is 10.6.0, have you tried upgrading yet? When reconnecting after an error, try clearing the IOHandler.InputBuffer of unread data before calling Connect().

Comment: Error is 10054 or 10060 (dont remeber). I think is 54 cause i have this link in browser history http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516579/recovering-from-connection-reset-by-peer-indy-tcp-client

Comment: I will try once again make a upgrade, maybe this time will be sucessful. If im not mistaken i already tried with IOHandler.InputBuffer, but will check again. Hard to test right now, cause problrems in my app is when twitch chat servers has problem.

Comment: i had this earlier, but it doesnt help (message box appeared)      IdIRC1.Connect;
      if IdIRC1.Connected then
        IdIRC1.Join('#' + Edit3.Text);
    except
       try
  IdIRC1.Disconnect;
  IdIRC1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
       except
  ShowMessage('!!!!!!!!!!!!!Nie można rozłączyć się')
    end;

Comment: What happens if you recreate the component (object) instead of restarting app?

Comment: how to recreate component? I just put IdIRC on Form

Comment: today i had this on app exit http://pastebin.com/hagqYtGq any idea?